# Abrir Modal Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou tendo dificuldade para abrir uma Modal com o Vue, estou utilizando o Vuetify, consigo abrir, como eles mostram na documentação, mas nao consigo abrir, apenas clicando em um botao (por exemplo).

```
<v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="600px">
    <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline"></span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text></v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn class="green--text darken-1" flat="flat" @click.native="dialog = false">Fechar</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Nesse caso, eu tentei abrir dessa maneira:

```
<v-btn primary flat @click.native="dialog = true" slot="activator">
    Detalhes
</v-btn>
```

Mas rapidamente ele abre e fecha sozinho. Alem disso, tem o Picker tambem, que vi na documentação que tenho a prop `opened` que recebe uma função, mas ele nao dao um exemplo de como abrir, alguem pode me ajudar?

```
<v-date-picker v-model="e4" autosave="true" scrollable locale="pt-br" format="DD/MM/YYYY" :date-format="date => new Date(date).toLocaleDateString()" :formatted-value.sync="formatted">
</v-date-picker>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para teres isso a funcionar tens de ter no teu componente uma propriedade (via `data`, `props` ou `computed`) `dialog`, que é o que o Vuetify espera. Depois é só mudares o estado desse valor entre `true` e `false`.

Repare que o `v-dialog` usa `v-model="dialog"`, isso quer dizer que é birecional, ou seja quando o dialog fechar ele vai mudar de volta o valor da propriedade para `false`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      dialog: false
    }
  }
})
```

```css
p {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccf;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p @click="dialog = true">Clica aqui!</p>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" width="600px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>
          <span class="headline"></span>
        </v-card-title>
        <v-card-text></v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn class="green--text darken-1" flat="flat" @click.native="dialog = false">Fechar</v-btn>

        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Voce sempre me ajudando, valeu rsrs. Nao testei o Picker ainda, mas vou testar e volto para dizer se funcionou. Abraço